# ReactiveUI/Splat Dependency Registration Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, reactiveui

I'm looking at [ReactiveUI Dependency Injection](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/dependency-inversion/) and there's something that is bugging me.

Normally I would register classes like this

```
Locator.Register<IToaster, Toaster>();
```

With Splat, it asks for registration like this

```
Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new Toaster(), typeof(IToaster));
```

The problem is that, in a real application, Toaster will contain 5 dependencies, each of which may have 2 to 4 dependencies each, some of which also have dependencies, and there's a whole tree to initialize. That's the whole point of Dependency Injection, to manage that.

Am I to do that work manually, or am I missing something? What are my options?

**EDIT: I found part of the answer. This is what I need: [Splat.DI.SourceGenerator](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/Splat.DI.SourceGenerator)**

BUT I can't find how to call SplatRegistrations.Register. It doesn't seem to be a popular library at all! Is going with ReactiveUI's default IoC the way to go or not?

**EDIT2: It seems easier to integrate another DI container than to use SplatRegistrations...**

Using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<MainWindowViewModel>();
services.AddTransient<CurrentTimeDialogViewModel>();
services.AddSingleton<IDialogService>(_ => new DialogService());
services.UseMicrosoftDependencyResolver();
```

but this is giving me thread exceptions all over the place.

How can I struggle with something so simple?

Answer (score 3):

[Splat.DI.SourceGenerator](https://github.com/reactivemarbles/Splat.DI.SourceGenerator) is the answer.

SplatRegistrations.Register wasn't recognized due to a bug in JetBrains Rider; but after restarting it, then it works.

Answer (score -1):

Try it

```
RxApp.MainThreadScheduler = AvaloniaScheduler.Instance;
```

after it

```
services.UseMicrosoftDependencyResolver();
```